# How to deref a pointer dynamically in Golang

Tags: pointers, go, dereference

I have this func:

```
func getStringRepresentation(v interface{}, size int, brk bool, depth int) string {

    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = *v.(types.Pointer)   // does not work
        val = reflect.ValueOf(v)
    }

   // ...

}
```

how can I dereference the pointer to get the value of it?  When I use:

```
v = *v.(types.Pointer)
```

The error says:

> Invalid indirect of 'v.(types.Pointer)' (type 'types.Pointer')

I tried this:

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = v.(types.Pointer).Underlying()
    val = reflect.ValueOf(v)
}
```

and I tried this too:

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    v = val.Elem()
    val = reflect.ValueOf(v)
}
```

I need to get the value of the interface{} from the pointer.

Comment: Consider using `reflect.Indirect` which will strip off one layer of pointer-ness for you, or do nothing at all of the argument isn't a pointer (but beware of using it on a `reflect.Value` from an interface value that compares equal to nil!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dereference pointers using reflect using `Elem`:

```
val := reflect.ValueOf(v)
if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
   val = val.Elem()
}
```

After the if statement, `val` is a `reflect.Value` representing the value passed in by the interface. If the value passed in is a pointer, `val` now has the dereferenced value of that pointer.

Comment: ok, so how do I then call this:
`v = val.Elem()
val = reflect.ValueOf(v)  // this does not seem correct`

Comment: You don't. After `v=val.Elem()`, `v` is already a `reflect.Value`. Note that in the answer, it is reassigning `val`, not `v`.

Comment: upvoted your answer, see my answer for the solution to the problem I had

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 'Elem' for access value referenced by Pointer.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {

    p := &struct{Hello string}{"world"}
    v := reflect.ValueOf(p)
    ps := v.Interface().(*struct{Hello string})
    fmt.Println(ps)
    s := v.Elem().Interface().(struct{Hello string})
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like this accomplished what I was trying to do:

```
func getStringRepresentation(v interface{}, size int, brk bool, depth int) string {

    val := reflect.ValueOf(v)

    if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = val.Elem().Interface()  // gets the actual interface from the pointer
        val = reflect.ValueOf(v)    // gets the value of the actual interface
    }

   // ...

}
```

thanks to the other answers which I stole the eventual solution from.

Comment: This is unnecessary. val.Elem.Interface dereferences the pointer, then gets the underlying value. Then you wrap the value again with reflect.ValueOf. val=val.Elem() is sufficient, and does the same thing.

Comment: it's not unnecessary but since you don't have the full context of what my func needs to do I understand. I need a reference to underlying interface and the value of that interface. calling `reflect.ValueOf(v)` after v becomes the underlying value is what I need.

Comment: You can use `val=val.Elem(); v=val.Interface()`